# Does $\bar A\cap \bar B=\emptyset$ imply $d(A,B)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let, $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$.
Is it possible that if $\bar A\cap \bar B=\emptyset$ then $d(A,B)=0$? I think it is possible, but I am unable to find an example.

*Note*:   $d(A,B)$ denotes the distance between $A$ and $B$. That is, $$d(A,B)=\inf\{d(a,b)\colon a\in A ,b\in B\}$$

Comment: What does $d(A,B)$ mean for you here? For the possible meanings I can think of right at the moment, $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[2,3]$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: When you use the word implies the interpretation is: whenever  the closures of the sets A and B are empty their distance is guaranteed to be zero.   You can easily see that is not the case. Please think about the meaning of your question.

Comment: On the other hand if $d(A,B)$ means $\inf_{a\in A,b\in B}d(a,b)$, then $\overline A\cap \overline B$ being _different from_ $\varnothing$ would imply $d(A,B)=0$.

Comment: In your example , $d(A,B)>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the question you mean to ask is: is it true that $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$ implies $d(A,B) > 0$?

I believe this is true for *compact* $A,B$, but false in general. Consider $A = \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $B = \{n + \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}\}$. Then, both $A$ and $B$ are closed, since they're discrete, and $A \cap B = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$, but for any $n$, we have $n \in A$, $n + \frac{1}{n} \in B$, and $d(n, n + \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{|n|}$, so $d(A,B) = 0$.

The converse to this statement is also true: if $d(A,B) > 0$, then $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$. Since if $x \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ with $d(a,x), d(b,x) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so $d(a,b) < \epsilon$.